# can I get individual MSM control panels to each use different colour theme?

Tags: control-panel, multi-site-manager

I have two sites running on MSM at the moment, however it seems that sometimes the editors and authors get confused about which site they are currently on, is it possible to get each site control panel to make use of a different colour?

For instance, the main site can use the standard blue/pink, the second site would display with blue/green in order to stop any confusion.

Comment: I have an extension for setting up different CP themes per site. Send me an email: max (at) eec.ms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MX MSM Themes](http://eec.ms/files/mx_msm_themes_1.1.0.zip)  - simple ext. which helps to setup CP themes for sites with MSM
[image]

Comment: Great, thanks Max! The add-on seems to work fine, I duplicated the default theme and was able to change the stylesheet colours easily enough for the second site.